# NodeJS Load/Stress tests results

Tags: node.js, load

I have developed a basic nodejs+express server which, for one route returns status 200 and perform a couple of load tests on localhost. The thing is that I cannot pass 1000 requests/second for this simple route:

```
app.get('/test',function(req.res){
    res.status(200).send()
}
```

For 1000 requests/s the server behaves alright, but after this the loadtest returns errors. How can I increase this value for nodejs, and, is this a good result? This is only a simple route without any processing so I think the server should accept much more requests. Thanks.

Comment: Please show your whole setup. If  you just use express, you should be able to serve more than what you want. But it's completely dependent on your hardware. I hope you aren't trying to reach that many request on a rasperry pi :)
With `ab -n 10000 -c 5 http://localhost:8088/test` I can get about 5000 requests per second.

Comment: my setup is just that route and app.listen(3000)

Answer (score 2):

There are so many factors that can influence your results. This is generally something that you shouldn't do on your own dev machine if you want solid, real-life results. The reason you shouldn't use your own dev machine is because it is always running something else that's completely unrelated to your app that uses your system resources - like Google Chrome, I/O, etc.
Another factor is your hardware and how saturated your system resources currently are.

If you still want to test locally I want you to keep in mind that the results will not reflect a production environment, hence the test is useless.
You can also improve performance a bit by using Node's [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module to make your server utilize all your machines' processor threads. Node.js is a single-threaded language.

Comment: Hello, I have already use clusters and, indeed, the power increase a bit. I understand your concern regarding the test machine, but still, is this result close to reality? I have the feeling that is very low..

Comment: You will _never_ get a result that reflect a production environment when tested on a local machine. It is not reliable. I suggest you run this test on your server machine instead to get a more reliable result. And `1000 req/sec` is **a lot**, even if it isn't a lot for a node app it's still a lot of requests.

Comment: I cannot understand why you stress the production environment. I am just performing some tests with node. Production environment will also have processing on the route not just a simple return so the number of requests will decrease significantly...